# Faucets are whistling

Tags: plumbing

This started about 2 months ago, and now whenever I turn on any faucet in house (*on low*), there's a whistling sound.

The whistling sound goes away if I increase the water flow.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: They probably just don't know the words.

Comment: Check your water pressure. Your PRV may have failed. When the tap isn't fully opened too high water pressure can cause whistling. Pressure should be about 60 to 70 lbs PSI.